# How many items can I have in "Completed Items" and how long they can stay there?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I abuse the Auction House to “increase” my stash size?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67423/can-i-abuse-the-auction-house-to-increase-my-stash-size)

I would like to know if there is a limit of items I can have in "Completed Items" page of Auction House; if yes, money that I got from successful auctions do count towards the maximum numbers of item allowed?

And finally, is there a limit of time I can leave items there or I can in principle leave them forever?

Comment: Oh, free storage!

Comment: **And finally, is there a limit of time I can leave items there or I can in principle leave them forever?** - You can claim the items at any point.  If you have 50 items already of course you will have to claim items before additional items appear.

Comment: More info about the Completed tab is also in: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67729/what-happens-to-an-item-that-doesnt-sell/67734#67734

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have 50 Items in your completed and Gold goes not count for it, as for time I do not truly know, but since you have paid for them item and it is in your ownership I would expect it to not disappear.

[image]